# Add View to Main User Control difficulty

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0, esri

Im building an extension for an app here's my problem.

There is a main Layout xaml page and this binds to the main applications datasource(meaning you can use different layouts on the app)

I created a View that I would like to place on this layout page. My view has its own view model which gets set once the "tool" gets clicked in the application.

This is the datasource for layout to conect to the main app

```
<Grid d:DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewerDataSource}}">
```

From debugging it hits my viewmodel everytime but never updates anything.

I add my view to the main layout like

```
 <!--Begin Custom Tab Item-->
                    <sdk:TabItem  Name="StatisticsTabItem" Cursor="Hand" Visibility="Visible">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <!-- Add Stats view here-->
                            <views:StatisticsView x:Name="StatsView" DataContext="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True}"  Grid.Row="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </sdk:TabItem>
```

So currently It sets a label on my view everytime and set its correctly but nothing gets updated on the actual view within the main layout xaml

I did set up my label as

```
private string totalPop;
    public string TotalPop
    {
        get { return totalPop; }
        set 
        {
            if (totalPop != value)
            {
                totalPop = value; 
                OnNotifyPropertyChanged("TotalPop");
            }
        }
    }

<sdk:Label x:Name="lbltotPop" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="{Binding TotalPop}" />
```

In my other applications it works fine but dont know how to set the binding to my view gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

Set the DataContext property of your view in the main layout XAML where your view is being instantiated (this will avoid having your view inheriting the DataContext from its parent).

Another thing you should avoid is to use the namespace "d:" for the DataContext property. Usually that namespace is used for the Design DataContext (hopefully that's not the one you're setting here I think).

Comment: Its a app builder and I'm only building an extension that fits into a layout of the app builder. It is already programmed as d:DataContext, should I still remove the d?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line
<Grid d:DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewerDataSource}}">
And see if the DataContext is initialized and pointing to the correct object instance (check FinalSource property in the Debug Locals Window). The d:DataContext is used to set the design DataContext instance not the runtime one. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602277(v=vs.95).aspx .
In addition you can set the Binding using just {StaticResource ViewerDataSource} instead of {Binding... Source={StaticResource ...}}

Comment: I have added my own view model on the main layout and looking at the debugger everything is properly connected now....Now the only problem is that the property changed stays null all the time even though it gets properly updated etc